# Перегрузка функции в kotlin по реальному типу аргумента

Tags: функции, kotlin, перегрузка-функций

По заголовку, скорее всего, будет сложно понять, о чём вопрос. Сейчас попытаюсь разъяснить на примере.

Допустим у нас есть интерфейс и несколько классов, которые его реализуют:

```kotlin
sealed interface IMyIntf

class MyClassA: IMyIntf

class MyClassB: IMyIntf

class MyClassC: IMyIntf
```

Теперь допустим, что у нас есть функции, каждая из которых принимает на вход один из этих классов. Так же допустим, что все эти функции являются расширениями к некоторому классу, который мы назовём `class MyEnviroment`. В данном случае важно не то, что конкретно он делает, а то, что он не даёт реализовать данные функции, как расширения к `MyClassA`, `MyClassB` и `MyClassC`, потому как это место уже занято `MyEnviroment`.

```kotlin
fun MyEnviroment.func(a: MyClassA) {/*какой-то код*/}
fun MyEnviroment.func(b: MyClassB) {/*какой-то код*/}
fun MyEnviroment.func(c: MyClassC) {/*какой-то код*/}
```

Задача: сделать такую функцию `func`, которая получала бы на вход аргумент типа `IMyIntf` и перенаправляла бы вызов в реализацию `func`, с соответствующим типом аргумента.

На текущий момент я использую для решения данной задачи такой подход:

```kotlin
fun MyEnviroment.func(intf: IMyIntf) = when(intf) {
    is MyClassA -> func(intf)
    is MyClassB -> func(intf)
    is MyClassC -> func(intf)
}
```

Но он имеет целый ряд недостатков, *не считая того, что это просто костыль*,:

1. Метод требует постоянного дополнения, при добавлении новых наследников у `IMyIntf`.
2. Много совершенно однотипной копипасты. Особенно, если наследников у `IMyIntf` будет много.
3. Для упрощения кода никак не используется тот факт, что `IMyIntf` - есть `sealed interface`, хотя если закопаться глубоко в рефлексию, то что-то на эту тему сварганить, конечно же, можно. Но рефлексия - это такое **ЗЛО**, к которому без крайней необходимости прибегать не хочется.
4. Просто выглядит некрасиво, как по мне.

Собственно хотелось бы узнать, вдруг в языке есть какие-то фокусы, которые позволили бы описать такую функцию один раз и навсегда, но желательно, без рефлексии и прочей опасной бяки.

Comment: И, да. Если вдруг кто считает, что пример высосан из больной фантазии, то сначала попробуйте поделать какую-то более или менее сложную логику на "Kotlin Js + React". Сразу поймёте, откуда у меня такие идеи.

Comment: почему бы в IMyIntf не объявить `fun func(e:MyEnviroment)` и в наследниках перегружать её?

Comment: @IR42, да. Действительно. Перестарался я, похоже, с упрощением примера. Получается, что в данном случае действительно ничего не мешает сделать `fun func(e:MyEnviroment)`. Дело в том, что в реальном коде у меня там не одно такое дерево с интерфейсом в корне, а лес классов и интерфейсов, наследующихся друг от друга. А в роли `MyEnviroment` может выступать, например, `RBuilder` из `React`. И у функций есть дополнительные аргументы, кроме представленных. В общем, если придумаю, как дополнить данный пример так, что бы не тащить сюда весь репозиторий, обязательно дополню.